# Certificate not being signed properly

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate, pinvoke, cryptoapi

I am creating some self-signed certificates through C# using p/invoked CryptoAPI calls for use in an application.  I am assigning the correct information to a CERT_INFO structure, getting the public key by using CryptExportPublicKey.  When I encrypt the certificate with CryptSignAndEncryptCertificate, the resulting value looks to be correct, but when testing with openssl -verify, I receive the following errors:

```
6704:error:0407006A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block type is not 01:.\crypto\rsa\rsa_pk1.c:100:
6704:error:04067072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:padding check failed:.\crypto\rsa\rsa_eay.c:721:
6704:error:0D0C5006:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:EVP lib:.\crypto\asn1\a_verify.c:221:
```

When checking the certificate in the CSR decoder at http://certlogik.com/decoder/, the modulus field of the public key information has a leading 00 byte that is not there when examining the public key with KeyPal.  Can anyone tell me what I need to do to fix this error?

Comment: What is `CryptSignAndEncryptCertificate`? Do you have any code? When using OpenSSL APIs, you usually just create the self signed certificate programmatically; you don't go through the intermediate step of a CSR. OpenSSL's `req` utility can create self signed. You use the command `openssl req -x509 ...`. `-x509` tells it to create a self signed, and not a request. You can find the source code in `<openssl src>/apps/req.c`.

Comment: CryptSignAndEncodeCertificate is one of the function calls in Windows CryptoAPI.  I'm not using openSSL.

Comment: Are you certain `CryptSignAndEncryptCertificate` is a Windows function? http://www.google.com/#q=CryptSignAndEncryptCertificate+msdn returns 0 results. If you are not using OpenSSL, then why do you have an OpenSSL error messages?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380277(v=vs.85).aspx

I'm getting the openssl error message because I'm using openssl as an independent means of verifying that the certificate is valid.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's interested:

The CERT_INFO structure that is passed into CryptSignAndEncodeCertificate contains a SubjectPublicKeyInfo field that is a CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO structure.  I was originally attempting to take the pointer received from CryptExportPublicKeyInfo and assign it to SubjectPublicKeyInfo via Marshal.PtrToStructure.  As it turns out, Marshal.PtrToSTructure just causes SubjectPublicKeyInfo to point to the same memory location as the returned pointer.  When the pointer is freed, the memory is invalidated and SubjectPublicKeyInfo is left in an undetermined state.  The way to get around it is to create a new structure and then assign this new structure to SubjectPublicKeyInfo.  This causes the values from the new structure to be copied to SubjectPublicKeyInfo so its memory location is never invalidated.  Or at least that's the nearest I can figure.  If anyone has a better explanation, I'd love to hear it.